How to Route Specific Paths to AKS Service and Others to an External Azure Web App in AKS Ingress?
I am using Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS) with the NGINX Ingress Controller to manage traffic to my application. I want to configure my ingress so that:
All requests to /v2 are routed to a Kubernetes service deployed in AKS.
All other requests (e.g., /, /v1) are routed to an external Azure Web App.
Here’s my current setup:
Kubernetes Service for /v2:
This works perfectly when configured.
External Azure Web App:
I tried using an ExternalName service to route traffic to the Azure Web App. Here's the service definition I used:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: azure-webapp
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my-webapp.azurewebsites.net
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 443

Ingress Resource:
Here’s the ingress configuration:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: harlyy-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: apidev.harlyy.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /v2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-k8s-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: azure-webapp
            port:
              number: 80

However, when I deploy this configuration and access the non-/v2 endpoints (e.g., /), I get a 404 Not Found error. The error appears to originate from the NGINX Ingress Controller.


Could you kindly try to use a proxy_pass annotation for external traffic

You are using an ExternalName service to route traffic to the external Azure Web App which means you are creating a service of type ExternalName that maps to my-webapp.azurewebsites.net. Nginx ingress cannot directly route to ExternalName service that points to external domains (like my-webapp.azurewebsites.net) due to limitations in DNS resolution.
Instead you can use a proxy_pass annotation for external traffic. It uses the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet annotation to configure proxy_pass for routing traffic to the external Azure Web App (my-webapp.azurewebsites.net)
Create an aks cluster or login to your existing one

Install nginx ingress controller


Create a deployment and service for your /v2
Sample-
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-k8s-service
  labels:
    app: my-k8s-service
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-k8s-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-k8s-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-k8s-service
        image: hashicorp/http-echo
        args:
        - "-text=Hello from /v2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-k8s-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-k8s-service
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80



Create or update the ingress configuration
sample service-
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dummy-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: non-existent


Update or create your ingress resource with routing rules
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: harlyy-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location / {
        proxy_pass https://my-webapp.azurewebsites.net;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: apidev.harlyy.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /v2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-k8s-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: dummy-service
            port:
              number: 80


Done. Get the external IP of the nginx ingress controller and update your DNS settings to point apidev.harlyy.com to the external IP of the ingress controller.

References:

Ingress in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
Create an unmanaged ingress controller

